# Is $(f\mapsto\int_\Omega f d\mu)\in L^1(\Omega,\lambda)^*$?

Tags: measure-theory

For $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ compact and some regular Borel measure $\mu\colon\mathfrak{B}(\Omega)\to\mathbb{R}$, is the mapping $$f\mapsto\int_\Omega f d\mu$$ a linear and continuous functional on $L^1(\Omega,\mathfrak{B}(\Omega),\lambda)$?

Can we show that the integral expression is bounded, or can we find a counterexample to it?

Edit: To avoid misunderstandings I would like to emphasize again that we are dealing here with two different measures $\lambda$ and $\mu$. Primarily I am looking for a counterexample of an $L^1$-function $f$ (with respect to $\lambda$) and a measure $\mu$ such that the integral of $f$ w.r.t. $\mu$ is no longer finite.
I have already played around with various $L^1$ functions and measures, but have never come to a contradiction.

Comment: Do you know what you need to show?

Comment: @Arctic Char I think so. But I'm having trouble deciding whether the integral is finite for all $f$, or not. For continuous functions this is easy.

Comment: Is the $\lambda$ a typo? Or is it Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Jose27 It is not a typo. $f$ is an integrable function w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure and I want to consider the $\mu$-integral of this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider any point $x_0 \in \Omega$ and let $\delta_{x_0}$ be the Dirac measure, i.e. $\delta_{x_0}(A) = 1(x_0 \in A)$ for any $A \in \mathfrak{B}(\Omega)$. This is a Borel regular measure. Define the function $f(x) = 1(x = x_0)$, so $f(x) = 1$ for $x = x_0$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. Then
$$
\int f d\delta_{x_0} = 1
$$
but
$$
\int |f| d\lambda = 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you. That would then be a contradiction to the boundedness of the operator, right?

Comment: I think your example shows even more: because of $f\sim0$ in $L^1(\Omega,\lambda)$ and $\int_\Omega f d\mu=1\neq0=\int_\Omega0 d\mu$ the operator is not even well-defined on its domain of definition.

Comment: That depends if by $L^1(\Omega, \mathfrak{B}(\Omega), \lambda)$ you mean the set of all integrable functions on $\Omega$, or the set of all the equivalence classes of integrable functions. In the latter case this counterexample fails.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to decide whether the integral of $f$ is finite or not. If $\int_\Omega f~\mathrm d\mu$ is not finite, then $f$ is not $L^1$ ! Now that we know all these integrals are finite, the linearity of the integral shows this map is linear, and hence is a member of the dual space of $L^1(\Omega,\mathfrak{B}(\Omega),\mu)$.

Comment: I only know that $\int_\Omega f d\lambda$ is finite. But now I integrate w.r.t. another measure.

Answer (score 0):

It is a basic fact that integration $I : L^1(\Omega, \mu) \to \mathbb{C}$ is a linear functional. It remains to bound the absolute value of the integral to prove that $I$ is continuous. This is straightforward since we have the identity
$$\left|\int_{\Omega}f\,d\mu\right| \leq \int_{\Omega}|f|\,d\mu = \lVert f \rVert_{L^1(\Omega)}.$$
Hence integration $I : L^1(\Omega, \mu) \to \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous linear functional with $\lVert I \rVert = 1$.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said this more clearly, but $f\in L^1(\Omega,\lambda)$ and not necessarily $f\in L^1(\Omega,\mu)$.